# SQL UPDATE based on conditions of other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do the following.

```
UPDATE account
SET new_finalleadsource =

CASE WHEN 
new_jtrack_source IS NOT NULL AND new_jtracksource <> '' 
THEN new_jtrack_source

CASE WHEN 
new_jtrackofflinesource IS NOT NULL AND new_jtrackofflinesource <> '' 
THEN new_jrackofflinesource

CASE WHEN
new_leadsource IS NOT NULL AND new_leadsource <> ''
THEN new_leadsource

ELSE NULL
END
```

Not sure if case can be used in this way, i'm basically trying to update a column with a value from 1 of 3 other columns depending on the first one that has data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple `CASE` statements, instead use single `Case` statement with  multiple `WHEN` expression's

Try this way

```
UPDATE account 
SET    new_finalleadsource = CASE 
                               WHEN new_jtrack_source IS NOT NULL 
                                    AND new_jtracksource <> '' THEN new_jtrack_source 
                               WHEN new_jtrackofflinesource IS NOT NULL 
                                    AND new_jtrackofflinesource <> '' THEN new_jrackofflinesource 
                               WHEN new_leadsource IS NOT NULL 
                                    AND new_leadsource <> '' THEN new_leadsource 
                               ELSE NULL 
                             END
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how the case statement works.  The case statement is like a series of checks of WHEN THEN.  Sort of like C switch with a break before each WHEN. So what you want is

```
UPDATE account
SET new_finalleadsource =
   CASE 
     WHEN new_jtrack_source IS NOT NULL AND new_jtracksource <> '' THEN new_jtrack_source
     WHEN new_jtrackofflinesource IS NOT NULL AND new_jtrackofflinesource <> '' THEN new_jrackofflinesource
     WHEN new_leadsource IS NOT NULL AND new_leadsource <> '' THEN new_leadsource
     ELSE NULL
  END
```

---

I think the following (based on Gordon's answer) is the most robust solution:

```
UPDATE account
  SET new_finalleadsource = 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(new_jtrack_source)), ''),
             NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(new_jrackofflinesource)), ''),
             NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(new_leadsource)), '')
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  However, if you don't want to change the value, then change the `else` to `else new_finalleadsource`.

One way to write the statement is:

```
UPDATE account
    SET new_finalleadsource = (CASE WHEN new_jtrack_source IS NOT NULL AND new_jtracksource <> '' 
                                    THEN new_jtrack_source

                                    WHEN new_jtrackofflinesource IS NOT NULL AND new_jtrackofflinesource <> '' 
                                    THEN new_jrackofflinesource
                                    WHEN new_leadsource IS NOT NULL AND new_leadsource <> ''
                                    THEN new_leadsource
                                    ELSE NULL
                                END);
```

An alternative is to use `COALESCE()` and `NULLIF()`:

```
UPDATE account
    SET new_finalleadsource = COALESCE(NULLIF(new_jtrack_source, ''),
                                       NULLIF(new_jrackofflinesource, ''),
                                       NULLIF(new_leadsource, '')
                                      );
```

Comment: I like NULLIF better, I was going to put a comment about coalesce if there were no empty strings.  I guess with LTRIM and RTRIM the NULLIF is the most robust and elegant solution